# Conflict between spring-boot-starter-webflux and spring-boot-starter-jetty

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, spring-webflux

I have a micro-service application, in one of the JAR dependencies i included the

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

so i can use reactive. 
in the micro-service artifact i want to use jetty embedded server, so i included

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now i got this error

```
The Java/XML config for Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux cannot both be enabled, e.g. via @EnableWebMvc and @EnableWebFlux, in the same application.
```

Which i think is due to adding webflux and jetty dependencies.
Any idea about this error and how to overcome it.

Comment: You will need to exclude Netty (as you now have both Netty and Jetty on your classpath).

Comment: hahaha, I wanted to say that it need to exclude the default server `Netty`.   But just now I created a demo with the latest version of Spring according to the configuration you gave. It used `Jetty` by default，and there are no errors like you described. So I stopped my anwser.

Comment: @ufan0, Based on this documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-use-another-web-server , it uses netty not jetty

Comment: @Melad Basilius, thank you for reminding, I konw that. Maybe a misunderstanding has arisen because of my poor english. :<

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-use-another-web-server) this is possible via excluding netty:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude the Netty dependency -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Use Jetty instead -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```